# Android: Activity is call finish automatically without calling

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have an **AppcompactActvity** called **Activity A**, inside **AppCompactActivity** i am calling Fragment. From the fragment am calling another **Activity B** at that time  I am not finishing the current Activity.

When I back press from **Activity B**. In OnBackPress its just finishing the current Activty B. When it reaches there its first calling to OnCreate then calling OnResume.

My Doubt is why its calling **onCreate** of **Activity A**. Because I didnt finish the **Actvity A** while callling **Activity B**

Can any please help for this doubt

Comment: which device you are using?

Comment: Xiamoi Redmi 1s @ tpA

Comment: When you move from activity A to activity B and activity A is no longer visible, it receives a call to the onStop() method that makes it releasing almost all resources that aren't needed. Once your activity is stopped, the system might destroy the instance if it needs to recover system memory. In such case, when you go back to activity A, it is possible that it needs to be recreated. In device developer options you have setting for forcing destroy of activities as soon as user leaves them.

Comment: Sorry Its my problem, In Developer options I manually enable Activity Kill on Background. This create issue.

Comment: This *may* happen even with that option turned off.  The purpose of that option is to make sure your program works correctly when it does happen.

Answer (score 0):

Call Fragment from Activity A like this:-

```
            fragment = new MyFragment();
            if (fragment != null) {
                title_tv.setText("My Title");
                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

Now Inside Fragment call Activity B , Use OnCreateView in Fragment:-

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_quick_list, container, false);

       Button create = (Button)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_create);
       create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),QuickList.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });



 // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return rootView;
}
```